# ngIf not working on custom NativeScript Angular ActionBar

Tags: angular, android-actionbar, nativescript

For some crazy reason I'm unable to get ngIf to work on or in the ActionBar.

I'm assuming this issue is caused by my custom ActionBar set up with `ActionBar.titleView`. However, from what I understand at the moment, I ***must*** have it set up this way in order to have a custom font for the title.

I have it set up as follows..

```html
<RadSideDrawer #drawer>
    <StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout">
        <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout">
            <Label [text]="name"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="sideStackLayout">
            <Label text="Dashboard" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Sessions" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Starred" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout tkMainContent>

        <ActionBar>
            <ActionBar.titleView>
                <Label text="Dashboard"></Label>
            </ActionBar.titleView>

            <ActionItem 
                *ngIf="!gameOn"
                id="startsessbtn" 
                (tap)="startSession()" 
                text="start"
                ios.systemIcon="4" 
                ios.position="right"
                android.systemIcon="ic_menu_add" 
                android.position="actionBar">
            </ActionItem>

            <ActionItem 
                *ngIf="gameOn"
                id="startsessbtn" 
                (tap)="endSession()" 
                text="end"
                ios.systemIcon="4" 
                ios.position="right"
                android.systemIcon="ic_menu_edit" 
                android.position="actionBar">
            </ActionItem>

        </ActionBar>


        <StackLayout>....</StackLayout>


    </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

What I'm trying to do is display an ActionItem depending on a Boolean value in this case `gameOn` but this just won't work.

Answer (score 2):

1. Place your ActionBar above RadSideDrawer, for example:

```html
<ActionBar>
  // etc.
</ActionBar>
<RadSideDrawer #drawer>
  // etc.
```

2. ActionBar.titleView doesn't exist in NativeScript + Angular, so you will want to use this setup for your custom title:

```html
<ActionBar>
  <StackLayout horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center">
    <Label text="Dashboard"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
  <ActionItem *ngIf="!gameOn">
    // etc.
  </ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
```

Comment: Reference to 1. Thank you for this info! I updated the html accordingly. About 2.,  I tried your example and it didn't solve the problem but I feel that it's most likely because of my ignorance of how and where I set the Boolean value so `ngIf` can evaluate it.  I'm gonna try to get some more answers on some related questions and I will update this thread once I know for sure this solves it for me.

Comment: Hey ZeroNine perhaps. these samples will help you out https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/ng-directives